# when i use where on json column on laravel return empty collection

Tags: json, laravel, collections, eloquent, where-clause

When I use this code in `laravel` for `json` where

```
 $users = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState','4');
```

`Laravel` returns an empty collection

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3909
   all: [],
}
```

How could i solve this issue?

Comment: try this: `$users = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState','4')->get();`

Comment: no , not working 
  ->first() work but   get() and another collection methods not working !!!

Comment: What do the JSON values of `meta` look like?

Comment: @kayvan Did you get it solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whereJsonContains` like

```
 $users = App\User::whereJsonContains('meta->Address->addressState', '4')->get();
```

or

You can use

```
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->where('meta->Address->addressState', '4')
           ->get();
```

I think where too work correctly may be you need to remove the quote

```
$users = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState', 4)->get();
```

or

```
$users = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState', "'4'")->get();
```

depend on how you have stored it in your DB.

Comment: @kayvan Can you confirm if `A` is capital in `Address` ?

Comment: @kayvan can you post some sample data including column name, may be a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState','4');

$data=$users->first();
```

This will work if you want  only one data from table that have  addressState of 4 else if you want multiple data  you can try this

```
$data=$users->get();
```

Comment: $user = App\User::where('meta->Address->addressState', '4');
    => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#3059}
    >>> $data=$user->get();
    => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3079
         all: [],
       }
    >>> 

not working

i want to get multiple data with     where('meta->Address->addressState', '4')->get();

Comment: please make sure  you have multiple data in your table  with addressState of 4

Comment: first try $user=App\User::get();  dd($user);  this will fetch all records from user table and try to add the where condition